# Scrolling Views Along with Collection View Cells

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

On my view controller I have 1 collectionview underneath 2 views at the top of the view controller I set the collection views height based on the size of the views so the collectionview is big enough that it doesn't need to scroll. All 3 views are inside of a scrollview so that I can scroll the views and the collection cells seamlessly. This feels very inefficient but i can't think of another way of providing this sort of seamless scroll between the views and the collectionview. Is there something else I can do to achieve the same or at least similar result?

EDIT: https://gyazo.com/8e5febea0974b0e6e0660f1714d67cbc this will hopefully explain it better. label is the view inside of the scrollview above the collectionview and four buttons are collectionview cells. Now if I add 20 buttons instead of only 4 I can scroll the collection view but it won't scroll with the  label. This might also help explain what I'm trying to achieve - http://jsfiddle.net/hDwPH/

```
Ignore This Dummy Code
```

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of what the app is showing, so I can assist further

Comment: Just edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screen shot, I assume that your view controller consists of

- 1 UILabel
- Multiple UIButtons
- Only 1 item per row

If so, you should consider using `UITableView` instead. The UILabel will be section header, The UIButtons will be the rows (`UITableViewCell`). So your UITableView consists of `1 section, 20 rows`.

1. If you want your UILabel to float along with the UIButtons, set the
   UITableView style to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`
2. If you want  your UILabel to remain fixed, set the UITableView style to `UITableViewStylePlain`

Comment: The tableview seems to be able to set something like this up easier than a collectionview Thanks!!

Comment: No worries. Glad that it helps.